# tf_echo can find transform but waitForTransform can't

Tags: ros, time, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, listening to the transforms between robot_center and laser_link from the network does not work anymore. In my Python script, I do:

```
self.tf_listener.waitForTransform("robot_center",
                                          "/base_front_laser_link",
                                          rospy.Time(0),
                                          rospy.Duration(5))
```

and get a timeout after 5 seconds.
From the same terminal, when I run

```
rosrun tf tf_echo robot_center /base_front_laser_link
```

It works and I can see the transform. Both my laptop and the robot's computer's time are synchronized using NTP.
Whan can be the reason for this behaviour?

EDIT:

I also tried running my script directly on the robot, still no difference, always timeout.

EDIT2:

I found out that a change was made recently in my robot where the static transforms are published with a time = 0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231914/tf_echo-can-find-transform-but-waitfortransform-can%27t/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2016-04-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that our robot's state publisher was changed such that most of static transforms representing rigid links were published using tf2 for efficiency reasons. Publishing them as static transforms, their timestamps are always set to zero. It was normal that waiting for transform did not work. Using tf2 however solved the problem.

```
    self.tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer()
    self.tf2_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tf_buffer)
    transform = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform("robot_center",
                                                "base_front_laser_link_horizontal",
                                                rospy.Time(0),
                                                rospy.Duration(10))
```

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2016-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2017-07-04**:
Aaaaahahhhhhhh. As a ROS noob, I banged my head against the wall for ~2.5 days on this exact issue. I'm following along with ROS Industrial tutorials, but doing them in `python`. This was exactly what went wrong (yet I suspected myself because I'm a noob and that was 10x more likely). Thanks!

**Comment by [felipeduque](https://answers.ros.org/users/49885/felipeduque/) on 2019-11-29**:
Hi! I'm sorry, I didn't quite understand. You said tf2 was used for efficiency reasons, and that static transforms in tf2 have their timestamps set to zero, but then you mention that you've used tf2 again to solve the problem. How did you solve it with tf2? @jwhendy

**Comment by [jwhendy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30308/jwhendy/) on 2020-01-08**:
@felipeduque just as above. They key is that instead of using the code [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28Python%29#The_Code), use the code [here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28Python%29#The_Code). Because the static transforms were published with `tf2`, you have to look them up using `tf2` vs. `tf`. Does that make sense?